# Heron's method in haskell

Tags: haskell, sqrt

I'm getting divide by zero exceptions in this code of heron's method, and I am kind of lost here.

```
epsilon:: Integral a => a
epsilon = 1

heron:: Integral a => a -> a
heron r = help 0
  where
    help x
      | abs (heron' x - heron' (x + 1)) < epsilon = heron' (x + 1)
      | otherwise                                 = help (x + 1)

    heron' 0 = 1
    heron' x = (1 `div` 2) * (heron' (x-1) + (r `div` heron' (x-1)))
```

Any suggestions where in this code I have to look to solve this problem?

`` (1 `div` 2) `` is definitely a problem , but what do I need to write instead?

Comment: Well, ```(1 `div` 2) * foo``` can be more accurately calculated via ```foo `div` 2```. But perhaps you would be better served by using floating-point or rationals...?

Comment: I tried using the Fractional Type so I can write (1/2) instead, but then I get an error for using the < symbol in my function..

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: @greentea, you may need to add an `Ord` constraint to your `Fractional` one.

Comment: Thanks guys, I added the constraint and now the function works fine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need division of this kind, you probably want to use `(/)` instead of `div` and `Fractional` instead of `Integral`. So:

```
epsilon:: Fractional a => a
epsilon = 1

heron:: (Fractional a, Ord a) => a -> a
heron r = help 0
  where
    help x
      | abs (heron' x - heron' (x + 1)) < epsilon = heron' (x + 1)
      | otherwise                                 = help (x + 1)

    heron' 0 = 1
    heron' x = (1 / 2) * (heron' (x-1) + (r / heron' (x-1)))
```